# Ubuntu restarting automatically when idle for some time

Tags: boot, 18.04, restart

Recently I had to reinstall Ubuntu (18.04 LTS) on my desktop. Now I am facing a serious issue. The issue is, when idle for some time, Ubuntu restarts automatically.

System Configuration:

```
Graphics : Intel® Haswell Desktop
GNOME: 3.28.2
OS Type: 64 bit
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4 
Memory: 3.7 GiB
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Why are there so many boot ooptions for Ubuntu ?

Also, I have now set the "black screen" to never. Still no change. Rather The frequency of restart has increased.

After doing 'last reboot' I get the following:

[image]

[image]

Update: now it is restarting every 3-4 minutes.

Comment: You have asked two very different questions, for best quality of answers you should ask one question at the time.

Comment: I am still having the issue. Shall I delete one question to have a solution?

Comment: Does `/var/log/messages` show any messages about why the machine shuts down? Or any of the other log-files in /var/log?

Comment: Please check the edited post. I have added a screenshot of log. Please let me know what more information I need to provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hardware problem. The SMTP got damaged.